# Release / Debug build generated json-rpc calls are different

Tags: web3js, react, ios

I'm trying to make simple web3 calls in React Native with web3.js, but generated json-rpc calls are different between release / debug builds - IOS/Xcode.

**Expected behavior**

```
    const web3 = new Web3(`https://ropsten.infura.io/${Config.INFURA_API_KEY}`);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {      
            web3.eth.getBalance(walletAddress, (error, weiBalance) => {

              if (error) {
                console.error;
                reject(error);
              }

              const balance = weiBalance / Math.pow(10, 18);
              console.log("================BALANCE================");
              console.log(balance);

              resolve(balance);
            });
          });
```

should return balance.
In Debug build, there is no problem.

**Actual behavior**

In Release build, it fails with `Node error: {"code":-32600,"message":"invalid json request"}`

i've inspected that in my release build the json -rpc request becomes like this:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xe1f42aa9aec952f61c5d929dd0b33690faaef976","latest"]}}`

whereas in debug build the json-rpc request is like this:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xe1f42aa9aec952f61c5d929dd0b33690faaef976","latest"]}`

how can the request get nested in the release build, this i don't understand...

#### Versions

- web3.js: 1.0.0-beta.48
- browser: react native 0.59
- ethereum node: infura

```
    System:
      OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
      CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
      Memory: 107.09 MB / 32.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 11.3.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.12.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
        Build Tools: 26.0.3, 28.0.3
        System Images: android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-24 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | GooglePlay Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3
      react-native: 0.59.0 => 0.59.0
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

**Release build json-rpc call made by simulator/device, captured by Charles proxy.**
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I've included console.log/error statements in **web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.umd.js** before every **sendPayload** statement, here is what i've found:

In Debug build, i get this, and everything works as intended:

```
2019-03-15 01:24:31.243 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'sendPayload_httpprovider_umd', { jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: 0,
  method: 'eth_getBalance',
  params: [ '0xe1f42aa9aec952f61c5d929dd0b33690faaef976', 'latest' ] }
```

In Release build. i strangely get this:
Notice how it first gets into sendPayload_CustomProvider_umd and nests the payload on sendPayload_httpprovider_umd

```
2019-03-15 01:17:10.433692+0300[48645:314312] 'sendPayload_CustomProvider_umd', { jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: 1,
  method: 
   { jsonrpc: '2.0',
     id: 0,
     method: 'eth_getBalance',
     params: [ '0xe1f42aa9aec952f61c5d929dd0b33690faaef976', 'latest' ] },
  params: [Function] }
2019-03-15 01:17:10.434 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'sendPayload_httpprovider_umd', { jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: 2,
  method: 
   { jsonrpc: '2.0',
     id: 1,
     method: 
      { jsonrpc: '2.0',
        id: 0,
        method: 'eth_getBalance',
        params: [ '0xe1f42aa9aec952f61c5d929dd0b33690faaef976', 'latest' ] },
     params: [Function] },
  params: [Function] }
```

I'm using

```
import './shim' // Provided by rn-nodeify --hack -- install
require('node-libs-react-native/globals');
```

in my start file, for react native web3 compatibility.

Comment: Release and Debug builds of what???

Comment: React Native with web3.js, added on the top of the question.
react native 0.59 / web3.js: 1.0.0-beta.48

Comment: Are you sure that web3 version is identical in both cases? Side note: I recommend sticking to v1.0.0-beta.37 or lower for now, since AFAIK, there are various problems reported for higher versions. I personally am currently sticking to v1.0.0-beta.34, which I have been working with for quite some time now, and I feel kind of confident in its stability.

Comment: Side note #2: `Math.pow(10, 18)` is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and is therefore likely to yield (hard-to-find) runtime issues in your code. Use `new BigNumber(10).pow(18)` or `new BigNumber("1e18")` instead.

Comment: Note that `web3.eth.getBalance` returns Promise which resolves to a `BigNumber` in web3 v0.x and to a `String` in web3 v1.x. So to be honest, I'm not sure how `weiBalance / Math.pow(10, 18)` even works, since according to your description, you are using web3 v1.x, which means that `weiBalance` is a string!!! In fact, to me it implies that your working case relies on web3 v0.x and your failing case relies on web3 v1.x. To be on the safe side, I suggest that you replace `weiBalance` with `new BigNumber(weiBalance)`, and then use `.toString()` or `.toFixed()` when you print it.

Comment: well, i didn't had a problem with that line before, but since you've said so, i've removed that line, and my problem seems to be not related to that, it still occurs. thanks for that.

web3 versions are the same, because the only thing i'm doing is changing the run scheme from debug to release.

Comment: @goodvibration question updated.